# Why is my BroadcastReceive causing a READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE denial on M?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I've got a broadcast receiver defined as follows:

```
  <receiver android:name="stuff.BroadcastReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
          <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
      </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
```

When the app runs on M then even though the app has been granted the Phone group permission I very occasionally can see this in the logs when there is an incoming call or on device boot.

```
 W/BroadcastQueue﹕ Permission Denial: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE flg=0x10 (has extras) } to stuff/stuff.BroadcastReceiver requires android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE due to sender android (uid 1000)
10-20 12:59:28.014  10946-10946/stuff V/BroadcastReceiver﹕ onReceive()
```

Although the receiver does execute.

Comment: I don't know if it is a bug in Android M or not, bug group permission logic is not working in Android-M properly, you have to go individually for every permission in group.

Comment: >>"you have to go individually for every permission in group." READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE is a system only permission.

Comment: Have you found any solutions, or workarounds?